# Motivation for gwt emulation java.util.EventObject

Tags: swing, gwt, emulation

What would be the use for GWT emulation of `java.util.EventObject` since it also provides `com.google.gwt.user.client.Event` as a kind of wrapper over DOM events?

I ask this because in the interest of emulating some swing components (JFrame and Buttons), and google does not provide such emulation. I intend to look at the `java.awt` sources and mimic it to run as JavaScript derived objects. And `java.awt.AWTEvent` descends of it.

I hope that this will help me develop faster by using the more known swing API in spite of learning all the GWT API: DialogBox, PopupPanel and much more that behave quite similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a web application you should use web apis. In my GWT time I have seen a lot of people using GWT as a wildcard for not learning how browsers work and thus producing really bad apps, that tend to be slow.

GWT is not about hiding the browser, but instead removing some quirks while highly optimizing your code. There is a reason that GWT apis are what they are like and simply emulating a few events will not do.

I spent myself a lot of time getting the Swing API to draw on a canvas with GWT, but the results were not really impressive...

Comment: +1: I really second this advice. Don't try to emulate Swing over GWT. All you will end up with, is fighting constantly GWT while not getting the Swing behaviour. GWT should be considered as a unifying layer on top of HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Yes I understand that. That I in desire are components. That is why I trying to emulate it as GWT components. Currently I trying to make an JFrame extending a GWT Composite class so I hide the implementation using a DivElement as the Window while providing the Widget interface, mapping the events over browser DOM events. For example the idea of glassPane is quite browser nice since it will use one DOM Element to receive events and dispatch it to target child elements.